# Why are the menu buttons not working in Mozilla firefox?

Tags: 16.04, firefox

So whenever I try to click a button in the menu option in firefox with my mouse it won't respond. I tried to reinstall firefox but it didn't help. The menu button is located on the top right side of firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Go to this website
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

and select the button saying refresh firefox:

> 1. Click this Refresh Firefox button directly, if you are viewing this
>      page in Firefox. **This won't work if you are using a different browser
>      or on a mobile device**.
>
>    - You can also find a Refresh Firefox button at
>        the top of the Firefox about:support Troubleshooting Information page.
> 2. To continue, click Refresh Firefox in the confirmation window that
>      opens.
> 3. Firefox will close to refresh itself. When finished, a window
>      will list your imported information. Click Finish and Firefox will
>      open.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, refreshing Firefox didn't work. What worked for me was to turn KWin compositing on (which I didn't know I had deactivated). That can be achieved by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>